# Write the contrapositive of an if-then statement

Tags: real-analysis, logic, proof-verification

> $\forall a, a' \in A,$ if $f(a)=f(a'),$ then $a=a'$

Here is my attempt:

$\exists a, a' \in A,$ if $\sim (a=a')$, then $\sim (f(a)=f(a'))$

Did I attempt to do this correctly?  I based this on the fact that if $p \Rightarrow q$ then the contrapositive is $\sim q \Rightarrow \sim p$

Comment: Are you just trying to state the negation?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry I don't understand your comment.  I'm trying to write the contrapositive of the given statement

Comment: The contrapositive would not change $\forall$ to $\exists$. The contrapositive is *equivalent* to the original statement.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews so if resolve that part the rest of the conversion to a contrapositive statement is correct?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negation flips $\forall \leftrightarrow \exists$. What you want is different. You have a proposition $P(a,a'): f(a)=f(a')\Rightarrow a=a'$. You want its contrapositive, which is an equivalent proposition that will *also* hold for all $a,a'\in A$.

So aside from mistakenly flipping $\forall$ into $\exists$, your form is correct. "For any two $a,a'\in A$, if $a$ is different from $a'$, then $f(a)$ had better be different from $a'$."

Comment: This makes total sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You got wrong the quantifier. The negations of contrapositive involve only the antecedent and the consequent. Since your formula is in prenex normal form (the universal quantifier in front of the whole expression and ranging all over it) you don't have to modify it. It should be $\forall a,a\prime\in A$ if $a\neq a\prime$, then $f(a)\neq f(a\prime)$.